# Need to query Calendar instance for Calendar setting to work

Tags: android, calendar, java.util.calendar

I have a Calendar instance that starts with the first day in December. I am trying to set that Calendar instance to the last Tuesday of the year. Somewhere between setting the last day of the year and the day of week, the Calendar instance reverts back to the original time:

```
Calendar cal = ....;
Log.d(TAG, String.format("Starting here %d-%d-%d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);

Log.d(TAG, String.format("Ending here %d-%d-%d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
/* Other stuff */
```

Gives me this output for 2017 and 2018:

2017:

```
Starting here 2017-12-1 
Ending here 2017-11-28
```

2018:

```
Starting here 2018-12-1 
Ending here 2018-11-27
```

### An Unsatisfying Fix

However, if I retrieve data from the Calendar instance, it works fine:

```
Calendar cal = ....;
Log.d(TAG, String.format("Starting here %d-%d-%d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

// Ask the Calendar instance for information
long dummyValue = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);

Log.d(TAG, String.format("Ending here %d-%d-%d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
/* Other stuff */
```

Gives me this output for 2017 and 2018:

2017:

```
Starting here 2017-12-1 
Ending here 2018-1-2
```

2018:

```
Starting here 2018-12-1
Ending here 2019-1-1
```

And yes, I know the dates for the second set of values are not the last Tuesday. That's what `/* Other stuff */` is for.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and poorly designed `Calendar` and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. I believe the observed behaviour is as documented. `Calendar` is just confusing, sometimes *very* confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    LocalDate myLocalDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 1);

    System.out.format("Starting here: %s%n", myLocalDate);
    LocalDate lastTuesdayOfYear = myLocalDate
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear())
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY));
    System.out.format("Ending here:   %s%n", lastTuesdayOfYear);
```

Output for 2017:

> ```
> Starting here: 2017-12-01
> Ending here:   2017-12-26
> ```

For 2018:

> ```
> Starting here: 2018-12-01
> Ending here:   2018-12-25
> ```

This *is* giving you the last Tuesday of the year. Nothing further is needed for that.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### What went wrong in your code?

The `Calendar` class is just confusing. In your case it is behaving according to the documentation. Allow me to quote:

> **Calendar Fields Resolution**
>
> When computing a date and time from the calendar fields, … there may be inconsistent information
>   (such as Tuesday, July 15, 1996 (Gregorian) -- July 15, 1996 is
>   actually a Monday). `Calendar` will resolve calendar field values to
>   determine the date and time in the following way.
>
> If there is any conflict in calendar field values, `Calendar` gives
>   priorities to calendar fields that have been set more recently. The
>   following are the default combinations of the calendar fields. The
>   most recent combination, as determined by the most recently set single
>   field, will be used.
>
> For the date fields:
>
> ```
>  YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_MONTH
>  YEAR + MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
>  YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
>  YEAR + DAY_OF_YEAR
>  YEAR + DAY_OF_WEEK + WEEK_OF_YEAR
> ```
>
> …

In your case `DAY_OF_WEEK` was set most recently. `DAY_OF_WEEK` is in three of the five combinations above. Which one it picks I don’t know. None of them also include `DAY_OF_YEAR`, the other field you set, so `DAY_OF_YEAR` is not being used. Which explains the behaviour you saw. If you insist on using `Calendar`, you should be able to get somewhere with `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, -1);` since negative values count backward from the end of the month.

However, `Calendar` is not only poorly and confusingly designed, it is also long outdated. So consider using java.time instead.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.